# using setTimeout to reload child component instead of ngOnChanges inside it

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, settimeout

Maybe for someone, this question will sound a little dumb. For me, is an unexpected behavior because I reuse a child component and I found that the data inside it are not updated when I change the source from parent. Because I don't want to implement `ngOnChanges` there (I try to avoid using it how much I can), an idea appear in my mind: use a boolean to hide and render the template again. But because the process is too fast, this will not emit. So, I need to use a `setTimeout` there (`100ms` are enough). **But is this approach ok?** This is my question. I tried to use `changeDetectionRef`, but still don't work, because inside the child component, all the logic are inside `ngOnInit` method, so will be fired only when the component is initialized.

```
<ng-container
   *ngIf="selectedView && !reloadChart"
   [ngSwitch]="selectedView.chartType">
   <app-line-chart
       *ngSwitchCase="'line'"
       [data]="selectedView.data"
       fxFlex="100"></app-line-chart>
   <app-pie-chart
       *ngSwitchCase="'pie'"
       [data]="selectedView.data"
       fxFlex="100"></app-pie-chart>
   <fa-icon style="position: absolute; top: 4px; left: 4px;"
       class="views__item__ok"
       [icon]="faCheck"
       (click)="selectView(view)"
       size="2x"></fa-icon>
</ng-container>
```

Because `selectedView` get same `chartType`, it will not update the chart data, so inside the `selectView` method, I added timeout:

```
selectView(view: View): void {
    this.reloadChart = true;
    this.widget.viewId = view.id;
    this.widget.requestType = view.requestType;
    this.selectedView = view;

    // stuff

    // this will force to render again the child component, 
    // because for 100ms, the reloadChart field will be true
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.reloadChart = false; 
      this.cd.detectChanges();
    }, 100);
}
```

Inside visualization panel is the problem (code displayed above). When I select one of the widgets from the carousel, it will change the child component to `selectedWidget.chartType` (`app-pie-chart`, `app-line-chart`, `app-table-widget`). The problem is when previous chart have same type as current chart, because inside the `[ngSwitch]` will remain same case. I don't want to modify the child component, but want to render it again inside the parent.

[image]

Comment: XY problem alert! `I found that the data inside it are not updated when I change the source from parent` : _this_ is your real problem. You should ask "Why is my child component not updated?" and focus on this, instead of asking "I tried this hack, is it ok?". So how do you update the data in the parent component? What's the code for this?

Comment: I explained why the data are not updated inside the child component, but you're right, this is more an hack than a solution :D Added an image inside the topic.

Comment: Thanks but the image doesn't help much. You should update your question with "Here's what changing in the parent component, and here's the `ngOnInit` logic in the child component". Currently your hack is to destroy the child component, and re-create it, so `ngOnInit` is run again. Surely thet's a clean way of achieving what you want, but we need the relevant code for it

Comment: For instance, I see you are using a chart library, but is it an `ng-*` version? Meaning, adapted for Angular, like [ngx-echarts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-echarts) instead of the regular [echarts](https://echarts.apache.org/)? Or [Angular2-chartjs](https://github.com/emn178/angular2-chartjs) instead of the regular [Chartjs](https://www.chartjs.org/)?